# How to use LWUIT NetworkManager

Tags: java-me, lwuit

Please can anyone give me some links to some helpful tutorial on lwuit networkmanager class. I have tried to study the docs, but it of little help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several samples in the [Codename One blog](http://codenameone.blogspot.com/search?q=NetworkManager) as well as a nice demo from [Eric Coolman](http://gadgets.coolman.ca/lazy-loading-implementing-an-infinite-list-in-codename-one/). Generally the usage is REALLY simple, just create a ConnectionRequest and add it to the queue for execution.